# Exceptions skipped in scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a scripted jenkins pipeline with the code like this.

```
func_stage_1() {
    try {
        stage1
    } catch {
    }
}
func_stage_1()
```

Initially when I did not have the stage inside function, pipeline used to fail if a stage failed and exceptions were printed. After putting it inside function, it continues the whole pipeline even though one stage fails. How to fix this?

Comment: Could you clarify: you have the stage inside a try... catch block. This means that any errors from the stage will be ignored and the rest of the pipeline will continue. Is this not the intended behavior?

Comment: sorry yes intended behavour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main functionality behind adding exception logic is to continue the process even though the stage is failed.

If you want to make the remaining process stop, if exception occurred then you have to do it in below way.

```
func_stage_1() {
    try {
        stage1
    } catch(Exception err {
         error "${err}" // stops the execution of remaining stages by throwing the exception
    }
}
func_stage_1()
```